# create an empty string in DATE format BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, date, datetime, google-bigquery, null

I need to create an empty string/null value. It has to be DATE type. I am UNIONing a couple of tables. Table 1 has date column, table 2 and 3 do not.
Below is the snippet of code for one table that doesn't have date column.

```
SELECT
      CAST(TIMESTAMP('') AS DATE) AS date,
      coalesce(id, 'unknown') AS id
FROM
`my_table`
```

I received the following error: `Invalid timestamp: ''`
Is there a way to create null value with DATE type?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select cast(null as date) as date
```

with output

[image]